# SSD firmware reverse engineering materials

Tags: firmware

Is anybody have materials about SSD firmware reverse engineering? I'm looking for links to suitable forums, papers, presentations etc.

Answer (score 3):

Having been interested in the subject for performance reasons - also curiosity - I couldn't manage to find much "**reverse engineering**" research on the subject.

But, I found very interesting information in the field of digital forensics. Information which can help understand some peculiar aspects of SSD, and memory in general.

You'll find an introductory set of links which provides valuable information at the bottom :

- http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Solid_State_Drive_(SSD)_Forensics
- http://digital-assembly.com/technology/research/talks/challenges-of-ssd-forensic-analysis.pdf
- https://articles.forensicfocus.com/2014/09/23/recovering-evidence-from-ssd-drives-in-2014-understanding-trim-garbage-collection-and-exclusions/
- http://www.macworld.com/article/1158234/ssdfirmware.html
- https://www.forensicmag.com/article/2013/05/forensic-insight-solid-state-drives

Hope you'll find what you're looking for or at least get close.
Enjoy !